# Python Code to create sheet name as a new column and merge all the sheets in Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python and what to see if there is a package to do the following:

I need to create an merged excel file which has the sheet name as a new attribute for every row in sheet

F1.xlsx has A35,A74,B97 etc., as sheet names 
F2.Xlsx has AX54,BT25 ETC.,C as sheet names

F1.xlsx

> Sheet A35 has
>
> ```
> col1  col2    col3
> XYZ       100     Ex-1
> ```
>
> Sheet B97 has
>
> ```
> col1   col2    col3 
> ABC    101     Ex-2
> ```

F2.xlsx

> Sheet AX54 has
>
> ```
> col1   col2    col3 
> XYZefg     110      Ex-3
> ```
>
> Sheet B97 has
>
> ```
> col1   col2    col3 
> ABCef   105    Ex-4
> ```

I want the final file to be:

```
col5    col4    col1    col2    col3
F1      A35     XYZ     100    Ex-1
F2      B97     ABC     101    Ex-2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFoin.jpg)

[image]

Comment: This isn't a basic programming question... in fact it is too broad. What have you tried?

Comment: The xlsxwriter package might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
import os
from glob import glob

f_mask = r'D:\temp\.data\47894067\*.xlsx'

df = \
pd.concat([df.assign(file=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0],
                     sheet=sheet)
           for f in glob(f_mask)
           for sheet, df in pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None).items()],
          ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
     col1   col2  col3 file sheet
0     XYZ  100.0  Ex-1   F1   A35
1     ABC  101.0  Ex-2   F1   B97
2  XYZefg  110.0  Ex-3   F2  AX54
3   ABCef  105.0  Ex-4   F2   B97
```

Comment: Thanks for Posting the solution Max. I am getting the following error. Are you using any other packages other than pandas, nupy,os and glob ???

-> 3081             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3082 
   3083     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'

Comment: @user5775949, this is strange, `df` in the loop should be a DataFrame, not a Series...

Comment: @user5775949, i hope you didn't add `squeeze=True` parameter when calling `pd.read_excel()`?